# can you create css class dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css

*emphasized text*
I am just studying and i want to create 100 css class dynamically

I want to do something like

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
  // create css class
  const newBackgroundColor = dynamicBackgroundColor();
  const height = '100%';
  const width = '0%';
  // add all 3 attribute to newly created css
}

// and then down the road, I want to use these 100 css class to 100 dynamically created div
```

Comment: thank you but no.. first I am not sure why that post answer starts with "i am not sure why you want to create css w/ javascript.. how else would you create css dynamically?" .. Also, I need to recall 100 css name and apply to newly create 100 div later.. I am not sure link has that solution.

Comment: Yeah, that is a little ambiguous. Actually you usually use JS to create `styles` and append them to elements, rather than whole new css classes.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes you can create dynamic css classes by the following

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = `
.class1 {
 /* Some style */
}
`;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

however in your case it would be easier to set the dynamic background color as inline style instead. While you generate the elements, just do `element.style.backgroundColor = dynamicBackgroundColor()`